# Difference in starting threading.Thread objects from a list in python3

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to do an exercise about the use of multi-threading in python. This is the task "Write a program that increments a counter shared by two or more threads up untile a certain threshold. Consider various numbers of threads you can use and various initial values and thresholds. Every thread increases the value of the counter by one, if this is lower than the threashold, every 2 seconds."

My attempt at solving the problem is the following:

```
 from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

class para:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.para = value

class myT(Thread):
    def __init__(self,nome,para, end, lock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.nome = nome
        self.end = end
        self.para = para
        self.lock = lock
    def run(self):
        while self.para.para < self.end:
            self.lock.acquire() 
            self.para.para += 1
            self.lock.release()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(self.nome, self.para.para)
            
        
         
para = para(1)

threads = []
for i in range(2):
    t = myT('Thread' + str(i), para, 15, lock)
    threads.append(t)

for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i].start()
    threads[i].join()

print('End code')

I have found an issue:
for i in range(len(threads)):
        threads[i].start()
        threads[i].join()
```

The for cycle makes just one thread start while the others are not started (in fact, the output is just the Thread with name 'Thread0' incresing the variable. While if i type manually:

```
threads[0].start()
threads[1].start()
threads[0].join()
threads[1].join()
```

I get the correct output, meanining that both threads are working at the same time

Writing the join outside the for and implementing a for just for the join seems to solve the issue, but i do not completely understand why:

```
for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i].start()
for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i].join()
```

I wanted to ask here for an explanation of the correct way to solve the task using multi-threading in python

Comment: `join()` will wait for thread to finish. So, you cannot have start+join inside same loop. Otherwise, we will start only 1 thread, then wait for it to finish. For your task, you want multiple threads to be running, so you must call `start` multiple times, and not wait for any to finish until after they all are started. So it's correct to have 2 loops as your last code shows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edit of your code and some observations.

Threads share the same memory space therefore, there's no need to pass the reference to the Lock object - that can be in global space.

The Lock object supports **enter** and **exit** and can therefore be used in the style of a work manager.

In the first loop we build a list of all threads and also start them. Once they're all started we use another loop to join them.

So now it looks like this:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

class para:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.para = value


class myT(Thread):
    def __init__(self, nome, para, end):
        super().__init__()
        self.nome = nome
        self.end = end
        self.para = para

    def run(self):
        while self.para.para < self.end:
            with LOCK:
                self.para.para += 1
            print(self.nome, self.para.para)


para = para(1)
LOCK = Lock()
threads = []
NTHREADS = 2

for i in range(NTHREADS):
    t = myT(f'Thread-{i}', para, 15)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print('End code')
```